# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 "Could not find table" Exception

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 could not find the table in Access 97 database although the table exists in the database while I try to insert records into table.

The code I used for insert is:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Genius\Office\Data Files\GeniusHistory.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

string query = @"INSERT INTO [HISTORY_OF_RECORDS]([OLD_CODE],[NEW_CODE],[TYPE],[OPERATION]) 
                 VALUES ('123','124',0,0)";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I control the schema using same connection object:

```
DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
dataGridView1.DataSource = schema;
```

The schema contains the HISTORY_OF_RECORDS table: [schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltfZ9.jpg)

When I try Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead of Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, it works without any exception. But when installing Access Database Engine on 64 bit machines; if there is 32 bit Office application, the customer has to uninstall all 32 bit Office applications.

The database file: [GeniusHistory.mdb](http://possistem.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/GeniusHistory.zip)

Comment: Then install the 32-bit version of ACE.

Comment: I tried 32 bit version of Access Database Engine but this time if there is an 64 bit Office application, 32 bit version of Access Database Engine cannot be installed.

Comment: Then install the 64-bit version on 64-bit machines. Install the version that is needed, that's the job of appication's installer. This isn't a question about tables, it's a question about installers, bitness and how to work with either driver. I suspect you'll find many relevant questions.